# Select either A or B with Or Operator in XPath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to crawl some websites, and the data I want can be found either of these places depending on the site:

Page 1:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li class="asd"> SomeText1 </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Page 2:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li class="dsa"> SomeText2 </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I would like an XPath expression which tries to select SomeText1 first, and if it doesn't exist, tries to get SomeText2.

I've tried `//li[@class="asd"]/text() or //li[@class="dsa"]/text()`, but this doesn't seem to cut it.

Am I using the `or` operator wrong? If so, how is it supposed to be used?

### EDIT

I'm trying to feed a crawler an XPath in order to find information to store in a DB. On a given webpage, can the information I'm trying to get be two different places?

Which means webpage 1 could be:

```
<AA>
  <BB>
    <CC> Test </CC>
  </BB>
</AA>
```

and on another there could be

```
<DD>
  <EE>
    <FF> Test </FF>
  </EE>
</DD>
```

How can I construct an XPath expression which can say either do
`AA/BB/CC` or (if it fails/doesn't exist) `DD/EE/FF`?

Comment: What version of XPath do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shorten it to:

```
//li[@class = 'asd' or @class = 'dsa']/text()
```

Having said that, "not working" is never an accurate description of what went wrong. A potential source of error is double quotes instead of single quotes. If there are double quotes arround the expression, any quotes inside must be single.

> Am I using the or operator wrong ?

No, your usage of the `or` operator is fine. Something else went wrong. (To really diagnose your problem, we'd need more context).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm mostly trying to figure out if i'm using the "or" operator correct. Appreciate your answer thou. Will the or operator choose the working expression if one of the conditions isn't present?

Comment: @user3489698 Depends on how you use the expression. Can you show more context?

Comment: Tried to udpate the explantion

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
//li[@class="asd" or @class="dsa"]/text()
```